# How do I add a number to a char that would result in the number being added "ASCIIbetically"?

Tags: c++, encryption

So right now, if I have `EncCode = 3`, and `MessagetEnc = 'f'` the Output is 105. I want the output to be "i". Also, why is the output 105 instead of "i" like what would happen in C?

```
  int EncCode; 
cout << "Encryption code: " << endl;
cin >> EncCode; 

char MessagetEnc;
cout << "Message to Encrypt:";
cin >> MessagetEnc;
 cout <<"Encrypted message:";

cout << MessagetEnc + EncCode;
```

I used `cout << "the message to encrypt is " << MessagetEnc << " and EncCode  is " << EncCode;` to see if  I'm getting the values mixed up but they aren't so I'm assuming it's the way c++ works. If I don't figure it out I'll just have to wait until I get a better understanding of how programming/coding works.

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions as C.

Comment: Hint: Use `std::string` not `char` which holds *one character* only.

Comment: @tadman It's for c++.

Comment: Yes, and I'm just saying you tagged it as C as well. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of an addition of `char` and `int` is an `int`; the equivalent C would be `printf("%d", MessagetEnc + EncCode)`.

Convert to `char` before printing.

```
cout << static_cast<char>(MessagetEnc + EncCode);
```